# Cross Account s3 to s3 without accessing AWS console

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am making a web service which helps in copying folders from user's s3 to our S3 bucket through AWS CLI. It contains upload and export functionality. I would like to know if there is a way to configure this without making changes in the AWS console.

**Here is what I have tried as of now for upload:**

[image]

In the front end, ask the user to provide the bucket name and the filename that he wants to transfer. Also, add the IAM access key and secret key in the AWS configuration.

```
// Configure aws with your accessKeyId and your secretAccessKey
aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,    
  region: process.env.REGION,
  bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET
});



// Now lets export this function so we can call it from somewhere else
exports.sign_s3 = (req,res) => {
    // S3 bucket setup
    s3 = new aws.S3();
    var sourceBucket = req.body.bucket;
    var destinationBucket = "destination";
    var objectKey = req.body.file;
    var copySource = sourceBucket + "/" + objectKey;
    var copyParams = { Bucket: destinationBucket, CopySource: copySource, Key: objectKey
};

s3.copyObject(copyParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log("S3 object copy successful.");
    }
});
};
```

But if you observe, some of the steps I've mentioned above are manually configured. I need to **reverse the process for export** and now user has to create IAM user and give the access & secret key along with their account number. How do I make them do it without moving out of my UI that's said not using their AWS console and how safe it is to share the above information?

Update:How do I make changes to the user's AWS account using API?

Comment: You don't need to use the AWS console for any of this. Everything is available through an API. For gaining write access to the user's S3 bucket, you should read up on cross-account access in IAM where one account can delegate access to another account.

Comment: @jarmod How do I make changes to the user's AWS account using API?

Comment: You use *your* credentials to assume a role in *their* account, thereby giving you temporary credentials for their account, and you then use those credentials to make API calls against their resources. There is never a need for them to share a secret key with you, or vice-versa.

Comment: @jarmod can you please explain what do you mean by "You use your credentials to assume a role in their account, thereby giving you temporary credentials for their account"?

Comment: Rather than try to iterate on this in stackoverflow comments, which is going to be difficult to do successfully, I would recommend that you consider one of the many good AWS education options or third-party video instruction because IAM is a core building block that you need to learn to be successful on AWS.